# Find a property name in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

lets suppose we have an array:

```
var array = [
{name1: 'value1'},
{name1: 1},
{name2: 'value2'},
{name2: 2},
{name4: [{name4a: 'value4a'}, {name4b: 'value4b'}]},
{name5: [{name5a: 'value5a'}, {name5b: 'value5b'}]}
];
```

where property names and values are random but some know names are repeated frequently. I would like to check if the array has specific property name (can be more then one), display it with index position, check what value does it have.

I can map the array and display proper property names, but cause I'm beginer I don know how to iterate over the results...

```
function extractArrayPropertyName(array, property_name)
{
    return array.map(function(item)
    {
        console.log(item[property_name]);
        // I want to display only the matched names, iterate over results and check the value
    });
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the keys of the object by using:

```
for(var key in array[i])
```

You are going to have to search recursively to find all the nested keys. I have thrown together a quick solution that does what you need:

```
function extractArrayPropertyName(array, property_name) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let key in array[i]) {
            if (Array.isArray(array[i][key]))
                result = result.concat(extractArrayPropertyName(array[i][key], property_name));
            else if (array[i][property_name] !== undefined)
                result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an itereative and recursive approach with a closure over the array of indices for the path to the element.

The result reads as follows:

> ```
> [
>     [0, "value1"],  // result 1 on index 0 with value 'value1'
>     [1, 1]          // result 2
> ]
> ```

or for a nested result

> ```
> [
>     [4, 0, "value4a"] // 4 and 0 are the indices.
> ]
> ```

```js
function getKeyIndex(array, key) {
    return array.reduce(function iter(path) {
        return function (r, o, i) {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                if (k === key) {
                    r.push(path.concat([i, o[key]]));
                    return;
                }
                if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                    r = r.concat(o[k].reduce(iter(path.concat(i)), []));
                }
            });
            return r;
        };
    }([]), []);
}

var array = [{ name1: 'value1' }, { name1: 1 }, { name2: 'value2' }, { name2: 2 }, { name4: [{ name4a: 'value4a' }, { name4b: 'value4b' }] }, { name5: [{ name5a: 'value5a' }, { name5b: 'value5b' }] }];

console.log(getKeyIndex(array, 'name1'));
console.log(getKeyIndex(array, 'name4a'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```